# При импорте файла, выдается ошибка invalid syntax

Tags: python, импорт, syntax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вод код:

```
    >>> import mymodule
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import mymodule
      File "C:\Users\art-a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\mymodule.py", line 1
        Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
                 ^
    SyntaxError: 

invalid syntax
>>>
```

Учусь по книге и, в данный момент, прохожу раздел "модули", там написано, что чтобы импортировать достаточно этой команды, но хоть я и сделал все что сказано в книге, ошибка все равно выходит
Вод код, импортируемой, программы:

```
def hello():
    print ("hello world")
```

Comment: Как это ни увидительно, но строчка `Python 3.7.1` и в самом деле не является корректным python-кодом. Сперва наведите порядок в файле, а потом уже импортируйте

Comment: Это часть ошибки

Comment: Сделайте скриншот файла `mymodule.py`

Comment: Сделал скриншот. Эта строка при открытии IDLE пишется автоматически и ее нельзя стереть, так же она не должна читаться, но читается, как я понял

Comment: Сделайте скриншот файла `mymodule.py` в нормальном текстовом редакторе, например в Блокноте или в WordPad

Comment: Загрузил, открытый в блокноте, mymodule.py

Comment: Вот, а теперь стирайте из файла синтаксически некорректный мусор

Comment: Да, спасибо. Все заработало

Comment: Есть еще один вопрос: нельзя ли как нибудь все это отключить, чтобы не заворачиваться?

Comment: Отключить что? Вас вроде бы никто не заставлял писать мусор в файл. Да вас в общем-то никто не заставляет использовать IDLE вообще

Comment: Прошу прощения, я ничего не писал кроме `def hello():
    print ("hello world")`. Все это появляется при запуске IDLE, возможно дело в ней... Я просто думал, что так не у меня одного и это можно отключить

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с комментарием `andreymal`, судя по `traceback'y` у вас первой идет строчка `Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` это одна из строк вашего кода, либо это было в книге, и вы случайно переписали, либо кидайте код детальнее (скрин консоли), вообще если зайти в консоль и запустить python, то у вас появиться 4 значка и туда написать `import modulename`, то это заработает, причем, судя по `traceback'y`, ошибка не в импорте, который работает, а в файле `mymodule.py`, скиньте сюда его код пожалуйста, если можно, или если в нем есть строка:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

удалите её.

Comment: Добавил скрин первой и код второй программы

Comment: Это часть ошибки

Comment: Объясняю еще раз: судя по traceback'y в файле mymodule.py по этому: `C:\Users\art-a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\mymodule.py` пути, у вас лежит файл в котором вызывается ошибка (это и есть файл который вы импортируете), а именно на __первой__ строке этого файла вы увидите такою строку: `Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`, вам нужно ее удалить т.к. она не имеет смысла, и я не знаю от куда вы ее взяли (возможно скопировали из книги)

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я добавил скриншот этой программы. Эта строка при открытии IDLE пишется автоматически и ее нельзя стереть, так же она не должна читаться, но читается, как я понял

Comment: Это строк нельзя стереть, но ее НЕ НУЖНО КОПИРОВАТЬ в файл! Вы просто скопировали в ``mymodule.py`` все содержимое окна, включая служебную информацию.

Comment: Все что я писал это код, при запуске эти строки появляются сами. Я ничего не копировал и не вставлял

Comment: хорошо, сделайте так откроете блокнот / sublime text / notepad++, напишите туда ТОЛЬКО КОД, КОТОРЫЙ ВЫ ПИСАЛИ, и сохраните с именем `mymodule.py`, в этой папке: `C:\Users\art-a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\`

Answer (score 0):

Файл `mymodlue.py` должен выглядеть так:

```
def hello()
    print ("hello world")
```

Вы же не глядя скопировали туда абсолютно все из IDLE, включая служебную информацию.

Comment: Я ничего не копировал, при запуске IDLE она появляется сама... Может у меня что то не то с самим питоном, но я писал только то, что вы привели комментарием выше

Comment: Как вы создали файл mymodule?

Comment: Зашел в IDLE через пуск, написал код, сохранил и дал название программе

Comment: Понятно. Когда вы просто заходите в IDLE, то это не редактор скриптов, а командная строка. Поэтому у вас и сохранилось все содержимое окна, включая служебную информацию.

Comment: Разве на скриншотах командная строка?

Comment: На втором и третьем - да, командная строка интерпретатора Python.

Comment: Тогда, нужно скачать Notepad++ или аналоги и писать код в них, чтобы избежать подобных случаев?

Comment: Можно в IDLE  создать новый чистый файл (File - New File или Ctrl  +  N). Запустить оттуда скрипт можно нажав F5.